# IHttpModule and threading

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, ihttpmodule

I have a class that implements [IHttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx). This is a support class to help my application defend against DDOS attacks. After implementing the `BeginRequest` method, I tried to debug my code and for some reason, each time that I debug the class, I have multiple threads in Visual studio. I can't understand why, all of the sudden, while running this application on my local machine, I'm getting several threads, and it happens only in this class.

Comment: what are you using to notice "several threads"?  I assume this is a web application, have you registered the IHttpModule in the web.config?  Is this an MVC web application (2, 3?) or just a classic ASP.NET web application?

Comment: When I debug a web application without a handler, I see 7 threads in the Threads window.  I'm not sure why this is a concern for you...

Comment: The application is a classic asp.net application, and yes, I have registered it at the web config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpModule probably intercepts all requests to your application, including files (js, css, images, etc.)

Take a look at the Request object of each request, and look at the Url property to see what is happening.

**Edit:**
HttpModules are active very early in the request flow, and they will often get hit by most requests for the server, so keep the code in the HttpModule to a minimum. An example: if you're making permissions on files, make sure the request is actually hitting a file (ie. the requested url starts with /files/). Whenever possible, cache data for use in HttpModules, don't go to the database for each and every request in a HttpModule!

The reason why you probably get less hits in your actual application, is that even requests for images, js files, css files, etc. might make a hit in the HttpModule, but in your application, only requests meant for the application will hit your break points (aspx, asmx, etc. for Web Forms and recognized routes in ASP.NET MVC).

To get a look at what requests you're handling in a HttpModule, look at the value of the url variable:

```
void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    String url = app.Request.Url.OriginalString;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses "several threads" in any way.

Comment: That is exactly how it looks like when debugging in Visual Studio, you're debugging several threads at once, because the VS web server (or IIS Express) handles several requests at once.

Comment: IIS or VS Web server has multiple threads without using an IHttpHandler and with just one request...  Whether or not there is multiple requests is irrelevant unless we know *why* the OP is concerned about several threads.  i.e. if you *always* have several threads, what is his concern?

Comment: Looks pretty obvious to me what it is he's asking. When debugging on his local machine, he think it's strange that the application is using several threads. On his local machine = one user, him.

Comment: 1) if it's one user; why would he have multiple requests?  If he made multiple request I don't think he'd ask about several threads.  2) he detailed "all of a sudden" in the context of an IHttpModule handler--associating several threads to IHttpModule handlers.  I'm saying you *always* get several threads, associating it to IHttpModule handlers is contrary to this and we need more information about *why* he's concerned.

Comment: 1 - Exactly - the moment the html arrives at the browser, it will fire off several requests.

Comment: Take a look at the answer, I've put in more info.